# Can one override "uname" on linux to allow for windows mingw cross compiler detection?

Tags: linux, windows, mingw, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross compile libraries (such as Metis) for Windows on Linux with mingw32-w64 and system configuration and compiler detection seem to make use of `uname -a`. Is there a way to "override" *uname* to return `Mingw64` instead of `Linux` to allow for convenient system detection, or would another approach be better?

Comment: Maybe there's a cleaner way, but you could write your own `uname` script, and make sure it is in your path before the real uname.

Comment: You can download prebuilt Metis using [quasi-msys2](https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/quasi-msys2).